# Schedule next UILocalNotification if app is not running

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I am working on an app for a trash company. The idea is as follow:
There is a calendar for 2012/2013 with dates when and what trash can (brown, gree and black) will be picked up.
I need to make a kind of notification system which will send a notification on a specific day (from that array) with some text about what container will be picked up this week.

That would not be smart to post all notifications at once coz there are over 100 (and I've heard the limit is 64 in iOS).

I thought to schedule next notification after the current one fires. This could be done in the kind of handleNotification method when user touches the action-button at the notification and goes to the app. But what if the user gets enough information from the notification window and never touches that notification, never goes to the app and mostly have it in the "non running" state at all?

How to schedule next notification then?
Maybe some smart heads can come with other ways to make it works without using UILocalNotification?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way.

If the user never opens up your app you will at most have 64 scheduled notifications. When all those have been triggered there will be no more notifications.

Although you can have your notifications repeating. So if the brown trash can will be picked up every week you can set a repat interval of weekly instead of scheduling it 52 times (thus saving 51 notifications).

Comment: Thank you Peter! But the sequence of picking is like each container is picked up every third week. And some of them are picked up every week So I need a kind of custom CalendarUnit which is not available yet today. Thank you for answer!

Comment: Yes that is unfortunately the problem with `UILocalNotification`s. So if you think my answer helped you with your problem please click on the checkmark that will motivate people to answering questions like yours.